# python specify css selector

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, css-selectors, webdriver

The webpage have a code:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <time data-timestamp="1458895194718" title="2016-03-25 11:39:54<small    class="milliseconds">.718</small>">11:39</time>
    </td>
    <td>
     <span class="invisep"><</span>
     <mark class="nickname" style="cursor:pointer;  color:#03DC03">usernickname</mark>
     <span class="invisep">></span>
    </td>
```

I need to get style= and I received advice to use:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import FirefoxProfile


    colorelement = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('mark.nickname')
    color = colorelement.get_attribute('style')
```

and it works but my code returns me only the first value found. The web page have many blocks  and everyone has block 
The code `find_elements_by_css_selector` returns "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'"
Could you help me please, how can I get second(third etc.) value or maybe it can be found all the values at once

Comment: The code you have uses `find_element_*` which only returns the first match even if there are more than one. It sounds like you want `find_element**s**_*` which will return all the elements that match. See Florent B.'s answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call get_attribute for each element:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('mark.nickname')
for element in elements:
  print element.get_attribute('style')
  print color
```

Or with a list comprehension :

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('mark.nickname')
colors = [element.get_attribute('style') for element in elements]
for color in colors:
  print color
```